# datetime object in JSONB in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, datetime, sqlalchemy, jsonb

Is it possible to have a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) object in a [JSONB](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) object (a structured format for storing JSON) in PostgreSQL 9.5.2 with SQLAlchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from datetime import datetime

class Object(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    attributes = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
```

And insert into the data base:

```
with transaction.manager:
    object = Object(attributes = {'name': 'miss piggy',
                                  'created': datetime.now()})
    session.add(object)
session.commit()
```

Gives me the following error:

```
StatementError: (builtins.TypeError)
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 7, 9, 51, 9, 893315) is not JSON serializable

[SQL: 'INSERT INTO object (attributes) VALUES (%(attributes)s)RETURNING object.id']
[parameters: [
    {'attributes': {'name': 'miss piggy',
                    'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 7, 9, 51, 9, 893315)}}]]
```

Comment: No, not directly. You can store it as a string (or dict), and then do some special parsing logic to determine that it's a datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, with the advise of [univerio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341730/univerio), the following function creates a dictionary from a datetime object and visa versa:

```
def DictDatetime(t):
    dl = ['Y','m','d','H','M','S','f']
    if type(t) is datetime:
        return {a: t.strftime('%{}'.format(a)) for a in dl}
    elif type(t) is dict:
        return datetime.strptime(''.join(t[a] for a in dl),'%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
```

Application:

```
# Create datetime object
a = datetime.now()
# Convert datetime object to dictionary
b = DictDatetime(a)
# Convert dictionary to datetime object
c = DictDatetime(b)
```

Check:

```
a == c
```

Returns: `True`